# jQuery slideToggle is adding white space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have found several similar questions on StackOverflow, but I am unable to figure out the solution for myself.

When you expand and collapse the table repeatadly, it adds empty rows to the top of the table.  How do I eliminate this behavior?

It's easiest seen on my fiddle: [My Code](http://jsfiddle.net/6u0580jq/)

Here is my jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.header').click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
tr.header {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

And here is the html (shortened for the sake of the question):

```
<table align="center">
<tr class="header">
    <td colspan="6" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold">20 Accounts are Uninsured - Click to Expand</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
    <td width="120">Account Number</td>
    <td width="200">Borrower</td>
    <td width="200">CoBorrower</td>
    <td width="220">Vehicle</td>
    <td width="110">VIN</td>
    <td width="120" align="center">View Policy Info</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
    <td>
        <div align="center">46546</div>
    </td>
    <td>Jerry Junko</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2004 Ford F-250 SD</td>
    <td>4SD65S46D4S6D</td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><a href="">View</a>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: With `.slideToggle(0)` you're not even taking advantage of the slide. If you change it to just a `.toggle()`, the problem goes away. Probably a glitch in the version of jQuery.

Comment: I did have it at 1000, but changed it to 0 for testing.  Switching to toggle worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, very tricky one but I found out that this issue belongs to the jQuery you are referring i.e. 1.6.4. Once you change it, you'll no longer see that glitch.

I recommend you to use the latest from 1.11.x or edge which is 2.x.x. These libraries have very good performance optimizations and new APIs and feature sets. `jQuery` 1.6.4 is fairly old.

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6u0580jq/2/

Comment: Also see it w/ jQuery 1.7.2 on the fiddle.. goes away at 1.8.3

Comment: yeah, older jQuery libraries had problem. like `1.6.x` and `1.7.x`